# structure have Application entry point

Tags: c#, .net, class, struct

Why we are not implementing in general, Application Entry point `Main` within in structure.

with refrence to C# Specification 5.0  `§3.1 Application Startup`  we can define Entry point inside the Structure for eg

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SampleApp
{
    struct Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

though `struct` is implicitly `sealed` ,then  what are the factors make `Main` should not be be declared inside the structure.

Comment: `Program` doesn't "feel" like a value type - we're unlikely to construct more than one of them anyway, but `struct` should be something you move to after careful consideration. Your default should be `class` unless you have good reasons for picking `struct` (for any data structure, not just this example).